# Icon resource usage in .dll project

Tags: c#, dll, icons

I have library project. I have .ico file inside "Assets" folder in library project. I want to create Icon from this file. How should I do this?

Comment: Try this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872957/how-can-i-use-the-images-within-shell32-dll-in-my-c-sharp-project

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps in order to set an icon:
•In Solution Explorer, Right click on the project node (not the Solution node), Choose Properties menu item.
•When the Project Designer appears, choose the Application tab.
•Under Resources you can specify icon. Browse to the location of the icon file that you want(Assets Folder).