# How to show folder icon with images like windows operating system in razor mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

**Gallery**

I have one requirement in my application where I am showing images when the user click on folder icon but I don't want to use plain folder icon instead of it  I want to show it as windows operating system pictures folder(where images will be displayed along with folder).

```
<div class="gallery-view">
    <img src="folderimage.png" onclick="getImages()"/>
</div>
<div class="show-images">
    <img src="image1"/><br/>
    <img src="image2"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use icons from `Shell32.dll` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872957/how-can-i-use-the-images-within-shell32-dll-in-my-c-sharp-project

Answer (score 0):

You can create the folder shape using CSS and then set the background-image property to the first image in the collection.

CSS:

```
.folder {
    width: 150px;
    height: 105px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-size: 100%; 
    background-image : url("http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/space/space-04.jpg");
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
}

.folder:before {
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
    background-color: #708090;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hK4pt/191/)