# Extract largest available icon with ExtractIconEx (or otherwise)

Tags: c#, winapi, icons

I am using ExtractIconEx to extract an icon by its index from shell32.dll as per this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62504226/9420881

I then take the output and convert it to an ImageSource like this:

```
ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                hIconLarge,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

From looking at shell32.dll I can see that a 256x256 icon is available for index 0, but it is a PNG rather than BMP:

[image]

The icon returned is not the 256x256 one, I assume its the 64x64 BMP:

[image]

How do I get the 256x256 PNG icon for index 0 (or any other index), if one is available?

Comment: You can use [SHGetFileInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfow) to get the index of the Icon (`.iIcon` member of the `SHFILEINFO` struct) in the System's ImageList. Then [SHGetImageList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetimagelist) to get the `IImageList` interface, specifying `SHIL_JUMBO`as the size of the Icon to return. The interface's `GetIcon()` function returns a HICON that can be used to generate the Jumbo (256x256) image

Comment: Unless there is an API to do that, you'll have to load the module and enumerate the icon directory resources. [The format of icon resources](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120720-00/?p=7083) explains how icons are arranged in a PE module. Doing this allows you to observe *all* icons for every icon group without the system doing its thing to pick the *"best"* one for you.

Comment: @Jimi SHGetFileInfo requires a path to be provided and returns an index. I already have the path "shell32.dll" and the index (0 for example). So not sure how I can use SHGetFileInfo in this case to get the 256 icon of that specific index, can you elaborate?

Comment: SHGetFileInfo gets the Shell Icon, the Icon that represents the file. You don't specify any index. The index returned is used to retrieve the Shell Icon from the System ImageList. This function is not used to extract resource from a file. If you're happy with the Shell Icon, then you're good to go. If you mean to extract any resource from the file, probably `EnumResourceNamesEx` + `GetIconInfoEx` + `GetObject` (if you need to get the names / ordinals first), or [LoadImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew) (`fuLoad` needs to have `LR_SHARED`)

Comment: If the image size you're requesting doesn't exist, IIRC the returned object is just the icon and the index / name specified, enlarged to match the size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an utility class that exposes the list of all icons handles (all sizes, all color counts) for a binary file (note: it cannot read .ico files).

It's based on [ICO Format specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)).

**Example 1**: loading an icon by index and choosing by size:

```
// load all icons handles with index 0 from a dll
var icons0 = IconInfo.LoadIconsFromBinary(@"c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll", 0);

// get the "jumbo" (256x256) one
var icon0_256 = icons0.First(i => i.WithIcon(i => i.Size.Width == 256));

// dispose loaded icons
icons0.ForEach(i => i.Dispose());
```

**Example 2:** Loading all icons for a binary file

```
// load all icons handles from a dll
var icons = IconInfo.LoadIconsFromBinary(@"c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll");

// ... do something

// dispose loaded icons
icons.ForEach(i => i.Dispose());
```

**Example 3:** Loading icons handles by id

```
// load icons with id "1" from a dll (same as index 0 for shell32)
// id is the value you see when opening the .dll from Visual Studio as a binary file in the ICON list of Win32 resources
// we pass it as a negative value
var iconsId = IconInfo.LoadIconsFromBinary(@"c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll", -1);

// get the jumbo one
var iconId_256 = iconsId.First(i => i.WithIcon(i => i.Size.Width == 256));

// dispose loaded icons
iconsId.ForEach(i => i.Dispose());
```

[image]
This is icon index 0, id "1"

Utility class:

```
public sealed class IconInfo : IDisposable
{
    private IconInfo(int groupIndex, string groupId, int index, string id, IntPtr handle)
    {
        GroupIndex = groupIndex;
        GroupId = groupId;
        Index = index;
        Id = id;
        Handle = handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; }
    public int Index { get; }
    public int GroupIndex { get; }
    public string Id { get; }
    public string GroupId { get; }

    public void WithIcon(Action<Icon> action)
    {
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

        using var icon = Icon.FromHandle(Handle);
        action(icon);
    }

    public T WithIcon<T>(Func<Icon, T> func)
    {
        if (func == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func));

        using var icon = Icon.FromHandle(Handle);
        return func(icon);
    }

    public override string ToString() => Index.ToString();
    public void Dispose() => DestroyIcon(Handle);

    public static List<IconInfo> LoadIconsFromBinary(string iconFilePath, int? byIndexOrResourceId = null)
    {
        if (iconFilePath == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(iconFilePath));

        var list = new List<IconInfo>();
        var handle = LoadLibraryEx(iconFilePath, IntPtr.Zero, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE);
        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            try
            {
                list = LoadIconsFromBinary(handle, byIndexOrResourceId);
            }
            finally
            {
                FreeLibrary(handle);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static List<IconInfo> LoadIconsFromBinary(IntPtr handle, int? byIndexOrResourceId)
    {
        var list = new List<IconInfo>();
        var entries = new Dictionary<ushort, GRPICONDIRENTRY>();
        var groupIndices = new Dictionary<ushort, int>();
        var groupIds = new Dictionary<ushort, string>();
        var groupIndex = 0;
        if (EnumResourceNames(handle, new IntPtr(RT_GROUP_ICON), (m, t, n, lp) =>
        {
            if (byIndexOrResourceId.HasValue && byIndexOrResourceId.Value >= 0 && byIndexOrResourceId.Value != groupIndex)
            {
                groupIndex++;
                return true;
            }

            string name;
            if (n.ToInt64() > ushort.MaxValue)
            {
                name = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(n);
            }
            else
            {
                name = n.ToInt32().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            if (byIndexOrResourceId.HasValue && byIndexOrResourceId.Value < 0 && !string.Equals((-byIndexOrResourceId.Value).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), name, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                groupIndex++;
                return true;
            }

            try
            {
                ExtractIconGroupEntries(handle, n, t, groupIndex, entries, groupIndices, groupIds);
                groupIndex++;
            }
            catch
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            return true;
        }, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            EnumResourceNames(handle, new IntPtr(RT_ICON), (m, t, n, lp) =>
            {
                var iconHandle = ExtractIcon(handle, n, t, entries);
                if (iconHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    var info = new IconInfo(groupIndices[(ushort)n.ToInt32()], groupIds[(ushort)n.ToInt32()], n.ToInt32() - 1, n.ToString(), iconHandle);
                    list.Add(info);
                }
                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static void ExtractIconGroupEntries(IntPtr module, IntPtr name, IntPtr type, int index, Dictionary<ushort, GRPICONDIRENTRY> entries, Dictionary<ushort, int> groupIndices, Dictionary<ushort, string> groupIds)
    {
        var handle = FindResource(module, name, type);
        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        var size = SizeofResource(module, handle);
        if (size == 0)
            return;

        var resource = LoadResource(module, handle);
        if (resource == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        var ptr = LockResource(resource);
        if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        // GRPICONDIR
        ptr += 2; // idReserved;
        var idtype = Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr);
        if (idtype != 1)  // idType, 1 for ICO
            return;

        var elementSize = Marshal.SizeOf<GRPICONDIRENTRY>();

        ptr += 2;
        var count = Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr);
        ptr += 2;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var entry = Marshal.PtrToStructure<GRPICONDIRENTRY>(ptr);
            ptr += elementSize;
            entries[entry.nId] = entry;

            // is it a string or an id?
            groupIndices[entry.nId] = index;
            if (name.ToInt64() > ushort.MaxValue)
            {
                var id = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(name);
                groupIds[entry.nId] = id;
            }
            else
            {
                groupIds[entry.nId] = "#" + name.ToInt32();
            }
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr ExtractIcon(IntPtr module, IntPtr name, IntPtr type, Dictionary<ushort, GRPICONDIRENTRY> entries)
    {
        if (!entries.TryGetValue((ushort)name.ToInt32(), out _))
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        var hres = FindResource(module, name, type);
        if (hres == IntPtr.Zero)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        var size = SizeofResource(module, hres);
        if (size == 0)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        var res = LoadResource(module, hres);
        if (res == IntPtr.Zero)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        var ptr = LockResource(res);
        if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        return CreateIconFromResourceEx(ptr, size, true, 0x30000, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    private delegate bool EnumResNameProc(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr lpszType, IntPtr lpszName, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool EnumResourceNames(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr lpszType, EnumResNameProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr lpName, IntPtr lpType);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int SizeofResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResInfo);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateIconFromResourceEx(IntPtr presbits, int dwResSize, bool fIcon, int dwVer, int cxDesired, int cyDesired, int flags);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr LockResource(IntPtr hResData);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hFile, int dwFlags);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    private const int LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE = 0x2;
    private const int LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE = 0x20;
    private const int RT_ICON = 3;
    private const int RT_GROUP_ICON = RT_ICON + 11;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    private struct GRPICONDIRENTRY
    {
        public byte bWidth;
        public byte bHeight;
        public byte bColorCount;
        public byte bReserved;
        public short wPlanes;
        public short wBitCount;
        public int dwBytesInRes;
        public ushort nId;
    }
}
```